# Code design, assigning static constant

Tags: c#, .net

In my app I have a static class called `Constants` which holds all of my global values which are accessed throughout my project.  A section of `Constants` looks like so:

```
internal static class Constants
   {  
       internal static DateTime FromDate = new DateTime(2011, 10, 1);
       internal static DateTime ToDate = new DateTime(2011, 10, 31);
       internal static decimal TaxRate = 20m;
   }
```

However now `TaxRate` is to be accessed dynamically from the database (and subsequently is available through an instance of an repository).  However since static constructors cannot have parameters how can I achieve this?

I'd like `Constants` to keep it's same properties:

- It's static, hence cannot be instantiated and have different versions
- It's properties cannot be modified (because of the `const` modifier)

However I'd also like to be able to set `TaxRate` from a reference object for the first time only.

What would be the best design to achieve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687403/c-sharp-static-constructors-design-problem-need-to-specify-parameter What type is your reference object? Can it be stored in dbms or config file?

Comment: First thing come into my mind is like this.. internal static decimal TaxRate{get; private set} .. so you can get the value but not set. When the application startups you can set the TaxRate via reflection.

Comment: It's a repository object, nothing special.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a "Static" class for this, why not consider using an IoC container with a scope of the usage of the class to be a Singleton() usage, or simply implement a singleton pattern against your Constants class, and then set the properties of the class to be a public getter with a private setter... you can then call an initialize() method to pull the required info from the database, but the rest of the code shouldn't be able to affect the values of the properties.

e.g.:

```
public class Constants
{
    static Constants instance;
    public static Constants Instance
    {
        get 
        {
             if (instance == null) 
             {
                 instance = new Constants();
                 instance.Initialize();
             }
        }
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
         // db logic here to populate db recorded fields.
    }

    private Constants()
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: The only thing I'm curious about with this after I thought about it... unless the public "getters" are readonly, you may still be able to change the values of the dates, but I've always had the rule that if I called it a static class, that i wouldn't attempt to change those values... just not sure how defensive it is or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could make them all Properties rather than instance variables that aren't private.  You can then provide getters without setters so that they cannot be modified elsewhere.

As for the complex initialization, you could then use lazy loading (if you make it thread safe).  Have private variables that aren't set, and when you 'get' one, if it isn't initialized, initialize it.